# Max area for a box

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am really stupid and I can't get this on my own. If $1200 cm^2$ is used to make a square box with open top what is the largest volume the box could be?

I set it up like so $$v = l w h$$

$$v = w^2 h$$
$$1200 = w^2 + 4wh$$

Where do I go from here? Everything I try in wrong.

I tried to make it like so

$$h = 300/w 0 w/4$$ to eilimate h but it didn't help give an answer that is correct.

Comment: I presume the constraint is area = 1,200 cm squared?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the **surface area** is fixed at $1200$ cm$^2$, then
$$
1200 = w^2 + 4wh \quad \Rightarrow\quad h = \frac{1}{4w}(1200 - w^2).
$$
Then you can find the maximum volume from:
$$
V = w^2h = w^2\frac{1}{4w}(1200 - w^2) = \frac{1}{4}w(1200 - w^2)
$$

---

If the **volume** is fixed at $1200$ cm$^3$, then
$$
1200 = w^2h\quad \Rightarrow\quad h = \frac{1200}{w^2}.
$$
Then you can find the minimum area from 
$$
A = w^2 + 4wh = w^2 + 4w\frac{1200}{w^2} = \dots
$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice trick you can use here, to avoid calculus altogether: If you make two such boxes, you can turn one of them upside down and rest it on the other one, to get a *closed* box. This closed box will have the maximum volume for a surface area of 2400 $\text{cm}^3$, which is a cube of side 20. (You can prove this without calculus, just using the fact that for fixed $a$, $x(a-x)$ is maximised when $x=a/2$.)

So each open box has a volume of $20 \times 20 \times 10 = 4000 \text{cm}^3$.